# How to Efficiently Graph Gradient/Hamiltonian Systems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We just went over Hamiltonian and Gradient systems, and I know easily how to determine if a system is one of the two.

For example:  $x+2y = x'$, $y' = -y$

$\frac{dx'}{dx} = -\frac{dy'}{dy}$ implies it is a hamiltonian system.

I know nullclines tell us about regions of behavior on the phase diagram, which in this case are just two lines ($x=2y$ and $y=0$).  But I'm stuck from here on how to effectively plot the graph.

Our hint is that the distinction of gradient/hamiltonian system will make it easier for us to graph the system, but I don't know why?

Answer (score 1):

Solved:  I'll just put a high level answer.

In both cases you want to find the level curves of the functions from which x' and y' are derived, so some sort of integration is usually involved in either x or y.

With the gradient/hamiltonian in hand, if the system is...

1. Gradient, then the level curves are orthogonal to the solution trajectories, going toward the equilibrium point.
2. Hamiltonian, then the level curves are themselves the solution trajectories.